# No aparece la imagen enviada desde la Base de Datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una app con `React`, `Node` y con la base de datos `MySQL`.

Estoy intentado hacer cartas que muestras las características de cada auto; Pero a la hora de cargar la imagen en la ruta hecha en `Node`, no me la carga.

Por lo que estuve mirando no puedo usar el método `res.send()` en la misma ruta 2 veces, entonces intente con el `else.if` pero no hubo cambios.

Si encuentran algún error avísenme, ya que quisiera saber cual es el motivo o si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema.

**Archivo Routes.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/datos/get', (req, res) => {

    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('server error')
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM autos ', (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err)
            } else if (rows) {
                res.status(200).send(rows)
            } else {
                rows.map(img => {
                    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../dbimages/' + img.id + '-' + img.modelo + '.png'), img.imagen)
                })
                const imageDir = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../dbimages/'))
                return res.json(imageDir)
            }
        })
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Archivo Home.jsx**

```js
const Home = () => {

    const classes = useStyles()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false) 
    const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/datos/get')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setDataList(res))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        })
    }, []);

    const redirigir = () => {
        navigate('/login')
    }


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <Container maxWidth='md' component={Grid} className={classes.container}>
            {dataList.map(data => (
                <Card key={data} sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }} elevation={4}>
                    <CardMedia
                        src={'http://localhost:4000/' + data.imagen}
                        component="img"
                        alt="..."
                        height="140"
                    />
                    <CardContent key={data}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                            {data.marca + ' ' + data.modelo}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            {'•  ' + data.año}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            {'•  ' + data.tipo }
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            {'•  ' + data.color }
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            {'•  ' + data.kilometraje + ' Km' }
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            {'•  ' + data.combustible}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActionArea>
                        <Button size="medium" className={classes.btnVerAuto}>Ver Auto</Button>
                        <Button size="medium" className={classes.btnVerAuto}>Ver Mas +</Button>
                    </CardActionArea>
                </Card>
            ))}
        </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**Captura de Pantalla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]